Login timeouts when using sssd to authenticate via Active Directory
I have successfully configured an Ubuntu Server 22.04 VM to authenticate with Active Directory, following the guide here: https://documentation.ubuntu.com/server/how-to/sssd/with-active-directory/.
However, I am seeing intermittent timeouts when attempting to authenticate with a domain account.
My guess is this is because the AD domain I am authenticating with is part of a large enterprise network, with many domain controllers distributed globally. If the client attempts to connect to a particularly remote DC, there is the possiblity that the login process exceeds some timeout.
My questions are:

Is there somewhere in the logs I can identify the specific domain controller that sssd is connecting to? I have been unable to find anything in /var/log/sssd.

I understand from the documentation here: https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/SSSD-Troubleshooting#SSSD-Troubleshooting that there is a configuration value ad_server which can be used, although this key is not present in my configuration. If I specify a particular domain controller, what happens if it is not available?

For Windows AD clients, 'Sites and Services' is used to locate a nearby domain controller. Does sssd have the capability to leverage this service?


Thanks in advance
